# How to perform an operation on a subgroup of a data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the percent change on specific subsets of a data frame based on their week number. The data frame looks like this:

```
      ref_dt   week_name  county_name  state_name   county_fips_code    cmi
0   2020-01-01  2020-W01   Broward      Florida         12011         3.651278
1   2020-01-02  2020-W01.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.851842
2   2020-01-03  2020-W01.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.868523
3   2020-01-04  2020-W01.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.748446
4   2020-01-05  2020-W01.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.650769
5   2020-01-06  2020-W02.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.878860
6   2020-01-07  2020-W02.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.899171
7   2020-01-08  2020-W02.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.907816
8   2020-01-09  2020-W02.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.913623
9   2020-01-10  2020-W02.  Broward      Florida         12011         3.919010
```

It has information for every county (here only showing a subset with Broward as an example) in the state of Florida and a mobility index calculated in the cmi column. The percent change is calculated by comparing the movement for the day of the week (ref_dt) with the average for the same days of the week. Here's an example for week1 and Broward after a sub selection I made in pandas.

```
df = counties[counties['county_name']=='Broward']
week1 = df[df['week_name'] == '2020-W01']
cmi_mean = week1['cmi'].mean()
week1['percent_change'] = week1['cmi']/cmi_mean * 100
```

The final output of the csv would look something like this (I dropped the state and county_fips_code):

```
      ref_dt    week_name  county_name    cmi      percent_change
0   2020-01-01  2020-W01     Broward    3.651278    97.259216
1   2020-01-02  2020-W01     Broward    3.851842    102.601642
2   2020-01-03  2020-W01     Broward    3.868523    103.045989
3   2020-01-04  2020-W01     Broward    3.748446    99.847497
4   2020-01-05  2020-W01     Broward    3.650769    97.245656
```

I want to apply the same logic for every week (1 to 14), for every county. What would be the best way to do this? do I need to reshape my data frame using pivot or stack and make columns for each week based on their week_name, or can I calculate the percent change with the current structure of my data frame?

Note: each average must be calculated for every week.

Comment: Groupby 'week_name' and 'county_name'. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.groupby` with `transform` and let pandas handle calculation alignment using indexes:

```
df['percent_change'] = df['cmi'] / df.groupby(['county_name', 'week_name'])['cmi'].transform('mean') * 100
```

Output:

```
       ref_dt  week_name county_name state_name  county_fips_code       cmi  percent_change
0  2020-01-01  2020-W01.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.651278       97.259220
1  2020-01-02  2020-W01.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.851842      102.601650
2  2020-01-03  2020-W01.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.868523      103.045982
3  2020-01-04  2020-W01.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.748446       99.847487
4  2020-01-05  2020-W01.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.650769       97.245661
5  2020-01-06  2020-W02.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.878860       99.363782
6  2020-01-07  2020-W02.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.899171       99.884084
7  2020-01-08  2020-W02.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.907816      100.105541
8  2020-01-09  2020-W02.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.913623      100.254297
9  2020-01-10  2020-W02.     Broward    Florida             12011  3.919010      100.392295
```

Comment: Thank you Scott! I spent my morning trying to crack this one up. I need to get better and practice chaining statements!

Comment: @Alonsoag You're welcome, I have spent just about everyday since 2016 practicing. :)